# Spectral Decomposition Grover operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics

I am studing the Grover operator. Let be $x_0$ the marked element. Let be $t_f = \pi/2\omega$. The measurement of the register in the computational basis return $x_0$ with probability

$$p_{x_0}(t_f)=\langle x_0|U^{t_f}|D\rangle|=1-1/N$$

Where $|D\rangle$ is a diagonal state state, $U$ the grover operator, $\cos \omega = 1-2/N$ and $N=2^n$.

My lecture say $p_{x_0}(t_f)$ is a lower bound for $p_{x_0}(\lfloor t_f\rfloor).$ $\lfloor t_f\rfloor=\lfloor (\pi/4)\sqrt{N}\rfloor + O(1/\sqrt{N})$ was obtained taking the asymptotic expansion in $N$. My question is Why  $p_{x_0}(t_f)$ is a lower bound for $p_{x_0}(\lfloor t_f\rfloor).$?